# Derivable encryption key - BIP0032 parallel

Tags: encryption, public-key, key-derivation

I wish to find an asymmetric encryption algorithm that supports key derivation, [BIP0032](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0032) style.
Meaning that I have some SEED [PRIV] and I give someone some public data [PUB],
then given new public data X (serial number for example), I can generate a new private key and this someone may generate the corresponding public key.

- It is important that given one (or more) of those private keys, you may not deduce the other private keys.

Do you know such a scheme?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Please clarify which scheme you want to use - RSA? DSA? ECDSA?

Comment: Hi Tal, thank you for the kind reply,
I prefer Elliptic Curve cryptography,
but any encryption scheme that will hold my requirement will do.

Comment: Which part of the bitcoin protocol pointed to does not meet your demands? Have you looked at [this similar Q/A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66793/1172)? Note that most of our users are not BitCoin aficionados, so that could be the reason for the lack of answers.