# Is it possible to derive a public key from another public key without knowing a private key (Ed25519)?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, key-derivation, ed25519

I have a following use case:

User has his master public (`pk`) - private (`sk`) key pair (Ed25519).
In DB we store a public key.
Is there any derivation mechanism `D`, where when knowing a derivation parameter `x` we can use it derive a new private key `sk2 = D(sk, x)` and public key (knowing only public key in DB): `pk2 = Dx(pk, x)` such that we can verify signature done by `sk2` using `pk2` ?

In other words, I would like to have a derivation mechanism I can use on the user side and server side, where server doesn't know private key.
Best if it works with Ed25519 keys.

Comment: There is the prior art of "implicit certificate", SEC #4 of http://secg.org/ although I'm not sure if there's a equivalent in Edward curve.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! You can use the ephemeral key derivation mechanism that is for example used in Monero (they call it stealth keys there).

Consider public key $A=aG$, with private key $a$. Then, a derived key can be generated, parametrised by the random scalar $r$:

$$A'=H_s(rA)G+A$$

and the party that knows $a$ can use the public parameter $R=rG$ to compute their ephemeral private key $a'=H_s(aR)+a$. You can for example store $R$ with your signature.

---

Note 1: We add $A$ resp. $a$ to the public resp. private key to ensure that the party that derives a key cannot compute the private key.

Note 2: This derivation is basically a Diffie-Hellman key exchange with a random ephemeral key $R$.

Note 3: $R$ can also be used to "check" whether the user has access to this specific key. He just needs to check whether $A'=H_s(aR)+A$ holds.

Comment: What is $H_s$? Is it a hash function?

Comment: Yes, it's specifically the hash function that maps onto the field; typically a hash function maps on a bit string $\{0, 1\}^b$. It's mostly a semantic detail though.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is possible using Hierarchical Deterministic (HD) Keys. There are 2 variations for key generation, **hardened** and **non-hardened**. In **hardened**, generating child keys (both public and private) requires knowledge of parent private key but in **non-hardened**, child public key can be generated using parent public key. You need **non-hardened** key generation. The cryptocurrency Cardano does this for ed25519 keys, [here is their doc](https://cardanodocs.com/technical/hd-wallets/) with more explanation. It is based on this [paper](https://cardanolaunch.com/assets/Ed25519_BIP.pdf).