# is it safe to do public key to public key derivation with Ed25519?

Tags: key-derivation, ed25519, bip32

Deriving a public key from a public key in Ed25519 is possible, some algorithms are available. My question is why there are so few implementations compared to secp256k1 for example. The extra checks necessary to implement it look at least more error prone than with other curves.

Comment: Do you mean to create ephemeral keys like this one [Is it possible to derive a public key from another public key without knowing a private key (Ed25519)?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66793/18298)

Comment: Yes, is related, but my question is if it is as safe as with secp256k1

Comment: A good question should extend the _some_ in the first sentence. The second sentence has a clear answer, The popularity due to the Bitcoin. The third sentence is dangling, the extra check of what? You can edit your question by clicking the edit.